# Flask web application, with handling for user login status

Tags: python, template, authentication, flask

I am trying to change some variable in base html-template which other html pages inherite from after entering user in personal account.

The idea is as follows:

- there is base html template and there depends on user status (logged in or logged out) are buttons `Registration` and `Enter`/`Exit`.
- if user is logged in then I want `Enter` button and `Registration` button to be dissappeared and instead of `Enter` button I want `Exit` button to be there
- in case if user is not logged in then two buttons should be: `Enter` and `Registration`

I managed to accomplish this task using flask, jinja2 and python but my backend code looks unbearably ugly because there is too much of duplication

Here is my python code:

this function executes before user gets to any html page and determines its status

```
from flask import g
from flask import render_template
@app.url_value_preprocessor
def send_user_login_status(endpoint, values):
    if current_user.is_authenticated: # if logged in
        g.login_button_class = u'logout'
        g.login_button = u'Exit'         

        g.signin_button = u''
        g.signin_button_class = u'signout'
    else: # if not logged in
        g.login_button_class = u'login'
        g.login_button = u'Enter'


        g.signin_button = u'Registration'
        g.signin_button_class = u'signin'

    return render_template("base.html",
                           login_button=g.login_button,                               
                           login_button_class=g.login_button_class,
                           signin_button=g.signin_button,
                           signin_button_class=g.signin_button_class,
                           )
```

And now I must every time pass variables to html page in order this page to be with needed buttons.

For example home page:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html",
                           login_button=g.login_button,                                                           
                           login_button_class=g.login_button_class,
                           signin_button=g.signin_button,
                           signin_button_class=g.signin_button_class,                           
                           )
```

or about us page:

```
@app.route('/about')
def about():
    # send_user_login_status()
    return render_template("about.html",
                           login_button=g.login_button,                            
                           login_button_class=g.login_button_class,
                           signin_button=g.signin_button,
                           signin_button_class=g.signin_button_class,
                         )
```

This is my python logout function:

```
@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    login_status = logout_user()
    if login_status:
        g.login_button_class = u'login'
        g.login_button = u'Enter'


        g.signin_button = u'Registration'
        g.signin_button_class = u'signin'


        jsonify({'result': True})
        return redirect('/')
```

**And as you can see there is too much of duplication because I need to pass this depends-on-login-status variables to each html page.**

Whereas html code looks nice:

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>

<body>
         <nav id="menu">
          <ul class="right">
                    <li class="{{ login_button_class }}"> {{ login_button }}</li>
                    <li class="{{ signin_button_class }}">{{ signin_button }}</li>
                </ul>
         </nav>
         <main>

                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
         </main>

</body>
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
 <h1>Home</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

about.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
 <h1>About</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite html code indeed looks nice, is there where you want to point out your efforts

Jinja supplies conditional blocks (like in python) where you can define which buttons you want to appear on screen, depending if user is logged in or not

This is a bare example

```
<div>
        {%+ if something %}yay{% endif %}
</div>
```

Following your example, your condition for user authentication can go in the template directly

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
  Hi {{ current_user.name }}!
{% endif %}
```

Feel free to read a bit more about options on templates on the following link for Jinja documentation

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/

Enjoy the coding :)